# stackdriver - showing count as percentages

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

We currently have logging setup with custom metrics that pulls the HttpResponseStatus from our logs using (?:HttpResponseStatus=)(...)

When this is put into a dashboard it will show a count of all the different status codes e.g 200, 204

What I am trying to work out is if its possible to have it show them as a percentage out of 100

example

```
200 95%
204 4%
500 1%
```

Is that possible using the Stackdriver dashboard and custom metrics? the logs resource type is currently Global

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the documentation for charts and alerting for Stackdriver and found no mention on representing the results as a percentage.

If you think this might be useful for you or/and other users maybe you should [go ahead and file a feature request.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187228&template=0)

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Monitoring doesn't really have the ability to calculate percentages, the way you're looking for.

Refer the Document:
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-selector

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Monitoring nee Stackdriver supports various query languages, including MQL and PromQL. If you use (one of) these languages, it becomes a matter of calculating the value you wish to display. I see this post covers getting a ratio of sums, and then multiplying by 100 so that you can get the percentage value: [How to calculate the percentage by label for gauge metrics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61442290/how-to-calculate-the-percentage-by-label-for-gauge-metrics)