# How to calculate the percentage by label for gauge metrics?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics, promql

I'm exporting some metrics about running tasks, the available data includes the current number of tasks by their status and queue:

```sh
# TYPE gauge
tasks{queue="high", status="queued"} 2.0
tasks{queue="high", status="started"} 1.0
tasks{queue="high", status="successful"} 5.0
tasks{queue="high", status="failed"} 1.0

tasks{queue="low", status="queued"} 1.0
tasks{queue="low", status="started"} 2.0
tasks{queue="low", status="successful"} 3.0
tasks{queue="low", status="failed"} 2.0
```

These numbers change regularly when the tasks are added or expired from the database, so for example the `failed` tasks number will go up and down depending on the tasks in the database at the time of collecting the data.

I don't have a way to get the total tasks count, so that's all the data that I have, I want to calculate the percentage of the tasks by their `status` label and create a graph of this value using **Grafana**.

How the percentage should be calculated?

What I've tried so far:

Get the percentage of all successful tasks:

```
( sum(tasks{status="successful"}) / sum(tasks) ) * 100
```

Get the percentage of successful tasks by queue:

```
( sum(tasks{status="finished"}) by (queue) / sum(tasks) by (queue) ) * 100
```

How can I get this percentage by time? For example when setting the time range in **Grafana**? I can use the variable `$__range` but how should I do the calculation?

I have other data where I have **count** metrics and I'm doing the following:

```
sum(increase(tasks_total{status="success"}[$__range])) /
sum(increase(tasks_total{status="started"}[$__range]))
```

But these are counts and these calculation don't apply to gauge metrics.

Comment: Looks like `sum_over_time()` with [$__interval]  is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

The per-`status` percentage for the currently running tasks can be calculated with the following PromQL query:

```
100 * (sum(tasks) by (status) / on() group_left() sum(tasks))
```

It uses `on()` and `group_left()` modifiers for `/` operation in order to augment the default behavior for matching time series on the left and the right side of `/` operation. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching) for details.

If you need to get per-`queue` per-`status` percentage for the currently running tasks, then the following query should work:

```
100 * (
  sum(tasks) by (queue, status)
    / on(queue) group_left()
  sum(tasks) by (queue)
)
```

If you need per-`status` percentage for tasks, which were run during the selected time `$__range`, then the following query should work:

```
100 * (
  sum(sum_over_time(tasks[$__range])) by (status)
    / on() group_left()
  sum(sum_over_time(tasks[$__range]))
)
```

It uses [sum_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum_over_time) function for aggregating the number of tasks over the given `$__range`. The `$__range` can be substituted with any supported time duration - see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-durations).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use group_left. See an example: https://www.robustperception.io/using-group_left-to-calculate-label-proportions

In your case:

```
sum without (queue) tasks{status="successful"}
/ ignoring(status) group_left
sum without (queue, status) tasks
```